# не работает модуль fs в electron js приложении

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

В моем приложении на electron js, мне нужно использовать модуль fs из node js, чтобы заносить и читать данные из txt файлов. И модуль отчасти работает. Я могу создавать папки и файлы, но почему-то их чтение и запись не дает никаких результатов. Например при таком коде:

```
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "newFolder", "text.txt"), "hello", (err) => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

В папке newFolder появляется файл test.txt, но он полностью пустой. Ошибок в консоль я также не получаю, и callback функция вообще не вызывается. Кто знает как это исправить, пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: у вас кончилось место на жёстком диске? что показывает iotop?

Comment: покажите больше кода или весь проект. и ещё смущает __dirname - в собранном состоянии это будет путь к временному каталогу. приложение запускается в собранном состоянии или пускачом электрона?

Comment: nörbörnën запускается в собранном состоянии

Comment: а. тогда гипотеза: удали-ка те файлы и каталоги, которые, как ты думаешь, создаёт твоё приложение. хорошенько всё поудаляй. запусти собранное приложение и выполни те действия, что как-бы должны привести к созданию новых файлов. спорю, что новые не будут созданы (там, где ты их ожидаешь увидеть). или ты показал не тот код, что этим занимается

Comment: в общем, что я заметил: если я вызываю код для создания файла или папки через консоль в открытом приложении, то работа с файлами идет успешно, файл создается и в него заносится результат. Но если я вызываю метод из своего объекта - это не работает, причем пути не различаются, я проверил и при вызове через консоль и при вызове через метод передаваемые пути - одинаковые

Comment: даже, не так, буквально вот так код из консоли не записывает данные в файл:

let filePath = path.join(__dirname, "newFolder", "test.txt");
fs.writeFile(filePath, "A2345", err => {console.log(err)});

при вызове этих двух строчек по отдельности - данные записываются.

Comment: ты мой эксперимент проделал? "пути" должны отличаються! 2рой вариант эксперимента: замени свой `__dirname` на `app.getPath('documents')` и посмотри в "Моих документах" будут ли создаваться файлы в 1вом и во 2ром способе запуска

Comment: Да, я все почистил. И затем вызываю, fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, "testFolder"), () => {}); - папка testFolder - появилась. Вызываю fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "testFolder", "test.txt"), "some txt", err => {console.log(err)}); - файл в testFolder  появился, но нет текста в нем. А по поводу второго - я не понял, как я могу обратится к компоненту app, если он в запущенное приложение не импортируется. Он же из init файла.

Comment: странно. давай проверим 2рую гипотезу. замени `fs.writeFile` на `fs.writeFileSync`, почисть запусти в режиме "из консоли", проверь, почисть, запусти в режиме "как приложение"

Comment: Результат: 
из консоли writeFile: запись не удалась,
из консоли writeFileSync: запись удалась,
из приложения writeFile: запись удалась,
из приложения writeFileSync: запись удалась,

то есть да, все сработало теперь наоборот. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что в следующий раз, оно сработает еще как-нибудь по другому. Потому, что это уже много раз происходило.

Comment: погоди. я правильно понял, что fs.writeFileSync дал тебе ожидаемый результат в обоих случаях?

Comment: Да, но вот fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "testFolder", "test.txt"), (err, content) => {console.log(content)}); - из консоли логируется буфер, а из кода приложения - ничего не логируется.

Comment: А, точно, я че то об этом не подумал, это же sync, тогда да, все работает, это я тупой просто. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: в общем, твоя проблема с fs.writeFile была в том, что ты уходил из потока выполнения до того как начиналась/завершалась запись в файл. не знаю что там у тебя в коде, но решается это или передачей/вызовом колбэка (или переходом на async/await), или заменой вызова на writeFileSync. Так как мы на ноде то я бы выбрал 1вый вариант, но смотри сам, по своим знаниям